# How to get id of child element when parent div event handler subscribed to the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

So i have a div like the following:

```
<div class="parentclass" id="parent">
    <select id="child1"></select>
    <select id="child2"></select>
    ...
</div>
```

I then have the following event handler:

```
$('.parentclass').on('change', function() { 
    alert(this.id);
});
```

This is alerting the id of the parent when i change the child options. So i am trying to alert the child id. I know that i can use jquery wildcards but is there another way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get target element from [`event`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object where [`event`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object can be accessed as the first argument of the callback.

```
$('.parentclass').on('change', function(event) { 
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

```js
$('.parentclass').on('change', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentclass" id="parent">
  <select id="child1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="child2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

Or bind event handler to the select tag using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if necessary or directly if elements are not generated dynamically.

```
$('.parentclass').on('change', 'select', function() { 
    alert(this.id);
});

// or without event-delegation
$('.parentclass select').on('change', function() { 
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```js
$('.parentclass').on('change', 'select', function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentclass" id="parent">
  <select id="child1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="child2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i needed

Comment: @Maxqueue : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select.select').on('change', function(event) {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentclass" id="parent">
  <select id="child1" class='select'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="child2" class='select'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

1. Instead of using parent element , since you know that you will be using select use it as selector.
2. You can also add class to the select then use it as selector

Answer (score 0):

why you not use class for select and write js onchange this class, alert($(this).attr('id'))

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use like `$('.parentclass select')`. this will get you changed drop down `id`

```js
$('.parentclass select').on('change', function() { 
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentclass" id="parent">
    <select id="child1">
     <option>option child1 1</option>
    <option>option child1 2</option>
    
  </select>
    <select id="child2">
  <option>option child2 </option>
    <option>option child2 1</option>
  </select>
    
</div>
```